# How to count distinct columns query?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony4

I have to find the total number or records but count is based on distinct of multiple columns.

I have following lines in my query.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder("j");
$query->select(
                "COUNT(DISTINCT 
                        'j.mark',
                        'j.model'
                    ) as total");
```

But this is giving me error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 76: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

Can anybody please help me solve this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you think the comma in `'j.model',` is needed?  I would also check the type of quotes you are using.

Comment: when I try ->distinct()->select('j.mark', 'j.model') it is returning records

Comment: You have an extra comma after `'j.model'`

Comment: No it did n't worked

Comment: @Nick nope that was not type. Extra comma only in question.

Comment: @NigelRen@Nick please look at my answer

Comment: Should it be `COUNT(DISTINCT j.mark,j.model ) as total"`

Comment: Why this topic is typo problem? All who voted for close. I clearly mentioned it's not typo causing me problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used concat instead which worked for me. But I am not sure if its the correct solution or not.

```
$query->select(
                "COUNT(DISTINCT(concat(j.mark, j.model))
                ) as total");
```